# When You Reload Page 404 Not Found In React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, hosting

I develop some project with react js. When I am using with localhost everything is fine. But when I publish this website and when you refresh page, page 404 not found is appear. I used `react-router-dom` and should I use anything else (apache express.js etc.)?

```
<Router>
  <Navbar/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' exact element={<Anasayfa />} />
    <Route path='/Hakkimizda' exact element={<Hakkimizda />} />
    <Route path='/Markalar' exact element={<Markalar />} />
    <Route path='/Sektorler' exact element={<Sektorler />} />
    <Route path='/Urunler' exact element={<Urunler />} />
    <Route path='/Iletisim' exact element={<Iletisim />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer/>
</Router>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283111/reload-the-page-gets-404-error-using-react-router ?

Comment: Where are you publishing your app? The basic issue is that the server hosting your app isn't configured to redirect all page requests to the root index.html file that is your React app so the app can handle routing/navigation internally. This varies by server environment. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) and find the section relevant to your server environment/hosting service to see what needs to be changed/set/configured/etc. In its current form we need more context to provide further help.

Comment: It was about i didn't create a .htaccess file in the public folder. That's why i had this issue. Thanks  a lot. It was a great document for me.