# React Custom 404 NotFound page isn't working in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have my 404 NotFound custom page properly working in development version, all other routes are perfectly fine, but after I built a production version I cannot get custom 404 page only a default one.

My route for 404 is:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={"/*"} element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

I used version only asterisk too path={"*"} , but it didn't work:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload the page gets 404 error using React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283111/reload-the-page-gets-404-error-using-react-router)

Comment: My pages work fine, I am talking about a custom 404 page which is not loading when it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Asterisk, like this, it should work:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={"*"} element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```